# Fitting plane to set of XYZ points

Tags: geometry

I have a set of $N$ points in form of their $xyz$ coordinates. I used approach where I bulid matrix $A$ in form of:

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    x_1 & z_1 & 1\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
    x_n & z_n & 1 \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

and matrix $L$ in form of:

$$
    \begin{vmatrix}
    y_1 \\
    \vdots \\
    y_n \\
    \end{vmatrix}
$$

then I calculate:

$$ x = inv(A^TA)A^TL $$

and:

$$ v = Ax-L $$

Where $v$ is vector of distances from each point to plane. The problem is, in comparisson to other algorithm I am using (RANSAC) some set of points give very poor results. I found out that it does not minimize distance to found plane but to one of the axes which is not what I am looking for. I am looking for minimal point-plane distances. Is it possible to adjust this approach? Or maybe is there a better way to find that plane equation?

Ideally I would like to have best fit plane equation in form of:

$$Ax + By + Cz + D = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have $n$ points and use the parameters $A,B,C,D$ for the plane then the mean square error you make is

$$MSE=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(C\hat z_i-Cz_i\right)^2=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(D-By_i-Ax_i-Cz_i\right)^2\tag 1$$
where $C\hat z_i$ is the approximation of $Cz_i$ based on $x_i$, $y_i$ and $A,B,D$.

This is a minimum problem: Find $A,B,C,D$ so that $(1)$ take its minimum.

Take the following derivatives and set them equal to $0$.

$$\frac{\partial MSE}{\partial A}=-\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^n(x_iD-Bx_iy_i-Ax_i-Cx_iz_i)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial MSE}{\partial B}=-\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^n(y_iD-By_i-Ay_ix_i-Cy_iz_i)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial MSE}{\partial C}=-\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^n(z_iD-Bz_iy_i-Az_ix_i-Cz_i)=0$$
$$\frac{\partial MSE}{\partial D}=-\frac2n\sum_{i=1}^n(D-By_i-Ax_i-Cz_i)=0.$$

That is, we have the following system of linear equations:
$$D\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-B\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i-A\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-C\sum_{i=1}^nx_iz_i=0$$

etc.

We have four such equations that we can solve.